# ActiveReportsJS Report Designer Component is affected by HashLocationStrategy in ASP.NET Boilerplate Angular Application

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, activereports, hash-location-strategy

I followed the instruction in https://www.grapecity.com/activereportsjs/docs/GettingStarted/QuickStart-ARJS-Designer-Component/QuickStart-Angular and made some modifications to integrate the ActiveReportsJS Report Designer in the ASP.NET Boilerplate Angular Application.

The report designer is integrated in ***src\app\home\home.component.ts*** and ***src\app\home\home.component.html*** in my ASP.NET Boilerplate Angular Application and ***HashLocationStrategy*** is applied in ***src\root.module.ts***.

Following are the screenshots of these files.

[home.component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAjtE.png)

[home.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUdrd.png)

[root.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS8KT.png)

[root-routing.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd0m4.png)

The problem is that when the ***HashLocationStrategy*** is applied in ***src\root.module.ts*** and I tried to enter the home page, the page is immediately redirected to the about page. I observed the URL and found out that the URL changed from http://localhost:4200/#/app/home to http://localhost:4200/# and finally to http://localhost:4200/#/app/about. I knew this is due to the routes setting in ***src\root-routing.module.ts***, but why this happened? The home page is actually there, but the application can't even recognize the route.

Meanwhile, I tested the following conditions:

1. When I removed the ***HashLocationStrategy*** from the ***src\root.module.ts***, I can enter the home page and the report designer can be rendered. The application did not redirect to the about page.
2. When I applied the ***HashLocationStrategy*** in ***src\root.module.ts*** and removed all the HTML codes from ***src\app\home\home.component.html***, I can enter the home page and it is a blank page. The application did not redirect to the about page.

Is this problem caused by the report designer itself? How can I make the report designer to render successfully in a page while preserving the ***HashLocationStrategy***? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the designer component. Please update to v2.1.1 which includes a fix for the issue.